# Angular 6 update specs [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular6

I am upgrading an Angular app to version 6 from version 4. Everything is running correctly with `ng serve`. The problem now is that a bunch of our spec files fail with `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`. I've seen this before and usually can run the test with `--sourceMap=false` flag to see a more detailed report, but now I still get this ambiguous error. I've checked that none of the components have any inputs that are undefined. After some research I found some people were having trouble with jasmine-core 3.0.0 and received this error until they went back to 2.99.0, but that did nothing for me either.

The oddest part about all of this is that I can `xdescribe` a spec (or all of the specs) that fail with this error and then different ones fail that weren't failing before.

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "enterprise-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --browsers=Chrome --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.0.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.5.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.111",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "^5.10.0",
        "typescript": "^2.7.2"
      }
    }
```

And here is one of the specs that is currently failing (most of them are much more complicated than this, but that makes me think it's not an issue with the tests themselves):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../modules/material.module';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NumberPerPageComponent } from './number-per-page.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

describe('NumberPerPageComponent', () => {
  let component: NumberPerPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NumberPerPageComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NumberPerPageComponent ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        MaterialModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NumberPerPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here's the component itself:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-per-page',
  templateUrl: './number-per-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./number-per-page.component.scss']
})
export class NumberPerPageComponent {

  resultNumber = 10;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue I was having was importing `HttpClientModule` into my specs instead of `HttpClientTestingModule`.

The tests were trying to make the api calls and failing when they were receiving 401 responses from our backend.

Comment: In my case, I also had to use `RouterTestingModule` and `ApolloTestingModule` in a bunch of places

Answer (score 3):

This kind of error is usually thrown directly into the browser : you see this message in your console, but the real error is the dev tools of your browser. Could you check that real quick and see if your error pops ?

Otherwise, it tells you which test is failing : try running this test asynchronously, or use the parameter from your callback :

```
it('XXX', done => {
  // do your things then
  done();
});
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning to open developer tools. Never would have thought of doing that for a unit test. Once I opened up the dev tools, there was the error.

Comment: No problem, a few people know that !